# How do I split the number and word in a .txt file

Tags: python, file, dictionary

The tempts1.txt is:

```
Living Room,23
Bedroom,24
Kitchen,22
Living Room,24
Bedroom,26
Kitchen,22
Living Room,25
Bedroom,26
Kitchen,23
Living Room,24
Bedroom,26
Kitchen,23
```

My Question is: I need to find the average for each room using this .txt file. How do I split the number and room so I can find the average temperature by using :

```
dict={} 
number={} 
for y in (tempts1.txt) as file:
  number = int(y[1])
  room=y[0]
  if room not in dict:
    room=number
  else: room+=number
for y in dict and number:
   print(dict[y],':',number[y])
```

Comment: Using the [`pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/) library comfortable for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one approach using a simple iteration.

**Demo:**

```
from collections import defaultdict

res = defaultdict(list)
with open(filename) as infile:
    for line in infile:                    #Iterate Each line
        val = line.strip().split(",")      #Split line by comma
        res[val[0]].append(int(val[1]))

for k, v in res.items():
    print("Room: {}, Avg: {}".format(k, sum(v)/float(len(v))))
```

*Edit as per comment* **Without Imports**

```
res = {}
with open(filename) as infile:
    for line in infile:                    #Iterate Each line
        val = line.strip().split(",")      #Split line by comma
        if val[0] not in res:
            res[val[0]] = []
        res[val[0]].append(int(val[1]))

for k, v in res.items():
    print("Room: {}, Avg: {}".format(k, sum(v)/float(len(v))))
```

**Output:**

```
Room: Living Room, Avg: 24.0
Room: Kitchen, Avg: 22.5
Room: Bedroom, Avg: 25.5
```

Comment: Am I able to use one that doesnt require to import functions.

Answer (score 0):

Get sum to one dictionary and count to another and take average:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(int)
count = defaultdict(int)

lines = txt.split('\n')
for line in lines:
    sep = line.split(',')
    d[sep[0]] += int(sep[1])
    count[sep[0]] += 1 

for k, v in d.items():
    print(f'Average of {k}: {v/count[k]}')

# Average of Living Room: 24.0
# Average of Bedroom: 25.5                                        
# Average of Kitchen: 22.5
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict

# Read data
with open('tempts1.txt') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
    data_read = [[row[0], int(row[1])] for row in reader]

# Group by room (fist value)
tempratures_by_room = defaultdict(list)
for room, temperature in data_read:
    tempratures_by_room[room].append(temperature)

# Output
for room, temperatures in sorted(tempratures_by_room.items()):
    print('{room}: {average}'
          .format(room=room,
                  average=float(sum(temperatures))/len(temperatures)))
```

gives

```
Bedroom: 25.5
Kitchen: 22.5
Living Room: 24.0
```